# AudioKit play notes on external MIDI keyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui, midi, audiokit

I use AudioKit to play notes via Mixer() and Sequencer(). I would like change the output node to an **external MIDI device** (e.g. piano) but can't figure out how to set the **output node** correctly. For illustration, following code plays some notes on the device (iOS) itself.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import AudioKit
import AudioKitEX

struct SongInfoView: View {
  let engine = AudioEngine()
  let sampler = MIDISampler(name: "MIDISampler")
  var mixer = Mixer()
  var sequencer = Sequencer()

  func playMIDI() {
    do {
        try sampler.loadSoundFont("Grand Piano", preset: 0, bank: 0)
           print("Soundfont Grand Piano loaded")
    } catch {
        print("Error loading Grand Piano soundfont")
    }
    
    mixer.addInput(sampler)
    
    let track = sequencer.addTrack(for: sampler)
    track.targetNode = sampler
    track.loopEnabled = false
            
    track.sequence.add(noteNumber: 80, velocity: 100, position: 0, duration: 1)
    track.sequence.add(noteNumber: 81, velocity: 100, position: 1, duration: 1)
    track.sequence.add(noteNumber: 82, velocity: 100, position: 2, duration: 1)
                
    track.tempo = 60
            
    for track in sequencer.tracks {
        track.targetNode = mixer
    }
            
    try? engine.stop()
    engine.output = mixer
            
    do {
        try engine.start()
        print("AudioKit engine started")
    } catch {
        Log("AudioKit did not start! \(error)")
    }
    print(engine.connectionTreeDescription)

    sequencer.playFromStart()
  }
...
}
```

I assume the solution evolves around:

```
midi = MIDI()
midi.createVirtualPorts()
midi.createVirtualOutputPorts()
midi.openInput()
midi.openOutput()
```